# Couldn't load delegate class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate

Tags: java, oracle, maven, quartz-scheduler

I have a problem with my driver delegate class in quartz Scheduler. I get the following error.

```
Caused by: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't load delegate class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate not found from bundle
```

But I have added the maven dependencies into my pom file and the dependencies are downloaded into my Maven repository as well.

```
<!-- Quartz dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

As far I know quartz-oracle-1.8.6.jar contains the `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate` class. Why I'm getting this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try to include new `quartz-2.2.1.jar` into maven or classpath.